# How to handle jQuery Ajax call on the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a get request using jQuery ajax, want to get the response on the same page. I tried this code...

```html
   
    <p>This is a Ajax get request.</p>
    <button class='send'>click</button>
    <p id='pritam'></p>

    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
        echo $_GET['name'];
        exit;   
    }
    ?>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".send").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: {name: 'praveen'},
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#pritam").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

But I am getting an error, It executes all page element again when I click on the button including button tag.

Comment: It would be very informative if you included the error in the question.

Comment: you better put php codes to the top

Comment: @Mitya, I am making the get request on the same page, so I don't think, I have to specify URL.

Comment: Is this ALL the code on the page? Is there a `<form>` on the page?

Comment: So you don’t _actually_ get an error message, but the behavior is not what you wanted? Those are two different things. _“It executes all page element again when I click on the button including button tag”_ - well yeah, of course it does … If you don’t want that, then _you_ need to wrap parts of the code in if/else constructs, that “execute” certain parts of it or not, based on whether the current request was an AJAX request, or a “normal” one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794859/detect-ajax-in-php

Comment: @JovylleBermudez, Thanks, you solved my problem but can you explain why is It necessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call the ajax page in same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351075/how-to-call-the-ajax-page-in-same-page)

Comment: @PraveenKumar because the HTML above it will be included as response to your ajax. that is why you should put it on the top. so you will have a clean response

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, No, that is a different question from mine.

Comment: To keep your project clean you should not mix up php code and frontend code. You can add a url to the ajax config and call an additional php file which processes your request and returns a json object. After this you can handle the data on success or failure. Good example found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
  <?php
    if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
        echo $_GET['name'];
        exit;   
    }
 ?>

 <p>This is a Ajax get request.</p>
    <button class='send'>click</button>
    <p id='pritam'></p>

    

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".send").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: {name: 'praveen'},
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#pritam").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your PHP section on top of this php file.

---

EDIT:

That's because a PHP file executed from top to bottom. When the ajax request was processing, the contents above the PHP section will output first. That will cause the data response you got contains page html tags.

Comment: I see you do not yet have **50 reps**, but this is really just a comment. This type of  answer attracts downvotes or gets flagged
___I did not DV___ and if that happens you will loose rep points and take longer to get to the 50 reps you need to comment on any question.
Until then, stick to questions that are well asked and therefore easily answered without
needing clarification. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: hi lindowx, you can explain this further, :) this answer actually helped